# React Router: Using HashHistory and trying to get location.hash

Tags: reactjs, url, react-router

I'm currently using a hashHistory in my SPA. When the user signs up they get an email to verify the account. When they click the verify button it will redirect to my website with a jwt token in the url

current website url:

```
website.com/#/
```

after clicking verify in the email:

```
website.com/#/dashboard#SomeReallyLongTokenValue
```

problem is, since I'm using hashHistory I can't do this:

```
this.props.location.hash
```

because it sees the first hash as the value now (which is an empty string). How do I fix this? I know moving to browserHistory would fix it but that's not possible at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a global [hashchange event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange) which is invoked everytime the hash changes, checks for presence of multiple hash characters and picks the segment you need and sets the correct hash.

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function (e) { 
    var fragments = e.newURL.split('#');
    if (fragments.length <= 2) {
        return;
    }
    location.hash = fragments[fragments.length-1];
});
```

Comment: I can definitely see how this would work but it doesn't with hashHistory. It seems like somewhere before it gets to my actual component the window.location is already changed to just `/dashboard` and my hash is gone